# Proving $m(kE) = k\cdot m(E)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove that $m(kE) = k\cdot m(E)$ given $k$ is a real number $k > 0$

 $m$ is Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$

Here's my proof.

Let $\{I_n\}$ be a collection of open intervals that cover $E$
$m(E) = inf(\sum l(I_n))$ 
$k\cdot m(E) = k \cdot inf(\sum l(I_n)) = inf(\sum k\cdot l(I_n)) = m(kE)$

This looks too simple and the book has done a much longer proof. 
What is the problem with this proof?

Edit:

I understood the problem in the proof, so if I add this, can I say that the proof is complete?

Since $\cup I_n$ covers $E$, then $\cup k \cdot I_n$ covers $k\cdot E$ for every cover. Now let $\cup J_n$ be an open cover of $k \cdot E$. Then $\cup \frac{1}{k} \cdot J_n$ is an open cover of $E$. Thus the family of $\cup k \cdot I_n$ consists of all open covers of $k \cdot E$.

Comment: The last equality $\inf\left(\sum k\cdot l(I_n)\right)=m(kE)$ is suspect for the following reasons: You have not constructed a collection of intervals that cover $E$.  You have implicitly used that $l(k\cdot I_n)=k\cdot l(I_n)$, which seems to be the whole point of the proof.

Comment: @MichaelBurr. Hmm... I don't understand. If I were to prove that $l(k\cdot I_n) = k \cdot l(I_n)$, will the proof be complete then?

Comment: No, you will only have an inequality.  You'll have shown that one family of coverings of $kE$ has the intended infimum.  You'll also need to show that all other coverings also have the intended infimum (or greater).

Comment: Also, which book are you looking at?

Comment: Lebesgue Measure and Integration by P.K. Jain, V.P. Gupta, Pankaj Jain. Understood! Thanks a lot!